# How do you change the selected option of a jquery selectric element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I can change the original select's selected option by doing something like-

```
$('#mySelectList option:first').prop('selected', true)
```

but that doesn't update the selectric display of the select.

Comment: Maybe you want to link to the plugin your are using.

Comment: sure, http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/index.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric/pull/26), you can "refresh" the plugin:

```
$('#mySelectList').prop('selectedIndex', 0).selectric('refresh');
```

From the documentation:

> `$('select').selectric('refresh'); // Reconstruct the instance of plugin`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was missing. You have to select an option and then call the refresh.  Like-

$('#mySelectList option:first').prop('selected', true);
$('#mySelectList').selectric('refresh');

Answer (score 5):

To change selectric by it's value, this works:

```
$('#mySelectList').val(someValue).selectric('refresh');
```